# Is it possible to return literals in a stored procedure to mimic a dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, string-literals

First off, sorry about the goofy question.

What I'm looking for is to return a "dataset" of hard-coded data. The reason why I need this or whether it's a good solution or not is irrelevant. I'd just like to know how I can do it.

I basically want to  return, via a `SELECT`, this "fake" dataset.

```
DisplayText  Value
-----------  -----
Yes          true
No           false
```

I'd rather avoid going through creating a table, populating it and then querying it if can. I'm thinking there's a clever way of doing this through the `SELECT`, but I haven't the skillz to do it.

Any help would be appreciated. Yes, I know this is goofy. Let's move past that. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "clever" but this should work:

```
Select 'Yes' as DisplayText, 'true' as Value
UNION
SELECT 'No', 'false'
```

Comment: Awesome, man. Thank you. Now I just have to count the minutes down until I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily for you now, but someday, and certainly for other readers, in SQL Server 2008 you can do this a little more succinctly (and it gets increasingly more succinct as you add more rows) using the new values constructor:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Yes','true'),('No','false')) AS x(DisplayText, value);
```

Again: this solution will only work in SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: Very cool. We'll be moving to 2008 at some point, so this will be good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select DisplayText = 'Yes' , Value = 'true'
UNION ALL
select DisplayText = 'No'  , Value = 'false'
```

Or you could do this in your stored procedure:

```
declare @temp table (
  DisplayText varchar(32) not null ,
  Value       varchar(32) not null ,
)

insert @temp values ( 'Yes' , 'true' )
insert @temp values ( 'No'  , 'false' )

select * from @temp
```

So yes, you can fake that sort of stuff out.

Comment: Sounds like he's not interested in the table solution.  From OP: `I'd rather avoid going through creating a table, populating it and then querying it if can.`

Comment: Yah, because it's such a small bit of data, I didn't want to go through all of that. Ya know, it's so much extra work and all. =)